# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp Error while deploying the spring boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, war

I'm trying to deploy my spring boot application in digital ocean ubuntu VM and I created a .war file and uploaded using Tomcat Web Application Manager. But I am getting an error as,

> FAIL - Application at context path [/springjwt] could not be started

> FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springjwt]]]

Then I checked the localhost log file in /opt/tomcat/logs and error is shown as,

> SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-26] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [ja$
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:129)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:58)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:159)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:191)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:383)

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @HariRam I posted the answer which solved my isse. Hope it helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at the sprinbootApplication.java file. The issue was caused because I have used the SpringBootApplication keyword in the following bold texted places was not my spring boot application name. That was the imported SpringBootApplication from the following class.

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

SpringApplication.run(**SpringBootApplication**.class, args);
return builder.sources(**SpringBootApplication**.class);

So you need to change the bolded places with your spring boot application name. Not with the above imported class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootSecurityJwtApplication extends 
SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(SpringBootApplication.class);
}
}
```